# Yii - How to get option value different in ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox from the name displayed

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using `ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox` to create a dropdownlist. When I use this I get the HTML as below :

```
<select id="SearchForm_max_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

but I want it like this :

```
<select id="SearchForm_max_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
<option value="5">five</option>
<option value="6">six</option>
</select>
```

I'm using the below code,

```
<?php
  $this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'min_cost',                                   
                     'data' => array('1','2','3','4','5','6'),                                            

                    'options' => array(
          'onSelect' => 'cost_change(item.value);',
                        'allowText' => false,
                    ),

                    'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'Min Cost', 'style'=>'width:70px'),
                ));


                ?>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->widget('ext.combobox.EJuiComboBox', array(
'model' => $myModel,
'attribute' => 'myAttribute',
// data to populate the select. Must be an array.
'data' => array('Y'=>'Yii','R'=>'Rocks')
'assoc'=>true,
....
```

));

```
'allowText' => true,
```

kullanımına örnek verilmiş. alttaki assoc => true an kaynaklanıyor olabilir mi? allow text i de true yapabilirmisin?

Comment: Still the same. Below is the HTML generated : `<select id="SearchForm_min_cost_select" style="display: none;">
<option value="0"></option>
<option selected="selected" value=""></option>
<option value="Bir">Bir</option>
<option value="İki">İki</option>
</select>`

Comment: can u tell me whr u found this